# C++ simple type serialization for streaming primitive- / pod types over a web socket (e.g. asio)

Tags: c++, io, stream

I am experimenting with asio web sockets and tried to write a simple serializer / deserializer.

I am also thinking about an approach on how to serialize some type information alongside the actual data. This way a dont have to worry about that i might choose the wrong type when deserializing.

```
// serialize.hpp

template<typename T>
struct serialize {
  static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T> || std::is_standard_layout_v<T>, "Only primitives and PODs can be serialized");

  std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)> operator()(const T& object) {
    auto buffer = std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)>{};

    const auto begin = static_cast<const std::byte*>(static_cast<const void*>(std::addressof(object)));

    std::copy_n(begin, sizeof(T), buffer.begin());

    return buffer;
  }
};

// deserialize.hpp

template<typename T>
struct deserialize {
  static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T> || std::is_standard_layout_v<T>, "Only primitives and PODs can be serialized");

  T operator()(const std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)>& buffer) {
    T object;

    const auto begin = static_cast<std::byte*>(static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(object)));

    std::copy_n(buffer.begin(), sizeof(T), begin);

    return object;
  }
};
```

Comment: I have a library that does this if it helps: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer Serializes into JSON/YAML/BSON with no extra code from you installed via brew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### std::is_standard_layout

`std::is_standard_layout_v<T> == true` does not imply that an object is a POD-type. An object is a POD-type if it is both `std::is_standard_layout_v<T> && std::is_trivial_v<T>`. Here's an excellent [summary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/trivial-standard-layout-and-pod-types?view=msvc-160).

---

### std::is_pod_v

If you're using C++17, or an older standard, you can use `std::is_pod_v<T>` to determine if a type is a POD-type.

---

### No need for `std::is_fundamental_v`

A fundamental type is guaranteed to be a POD-type.

---

### Use `std::is_trivially_copyable_v`

There are types which are memcpy-able but not POD-types. For example,

```cpp
struct NonPODButMemcpyableType
{
    int x = 42;
}
```

The existence of the default value disqualifies it from being a POD-type. It will raise a compile error, but it should still be (de)serializable. You should `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>` instead.

---

The cast to `const void*` can be avoided if you use `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>`. It is legal in this case, since you're casting to a char type.

---